# Dynamically adding content to HTML page using JavaScript (and JQuery) - how to access new content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML file that contains only the basic elements (html, head, body, ...) and I want to fill it up with content stored in an external file ("content.html") in my case, using JavaScript (and JQuery). I have accomplished that with function $.get(), but I don't know, how to access the information I got with this function.

For example, I want to throw an alert if a link is clicked. My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $.get("content.html", addContent);   // calls addContent

       function addContent(data)            // fills <div id='content'> with content.html
       {
          $("#content").html(data);
          alert('Load was performed.');
       }


       $("a").click(function(event){ // !!!if any link is clicked, throw an alert 
         alert("Link clicked");
         event.preventDefault();
       });

     });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
  <!--CONTENT OF content.html WILL BE INSERTED HERE-->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how content.html looks like:

```
<h1>Band Creator Home</h1>
    <p>Currently following apps are available:</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/bands/">Bands</a></li>
        <li><a href="/instruments/">Instruments</a></li>
        <li><a href="/musicians/">Musicians</a></li>
        <span></span>
    </ul>
```

Since there is no  element in the original HTML, alert "Link clicked" is never thrown. How can I access these elements collected by $.get() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous.
The server only sends a reply some time after the `get` method finishes.

Therefore, you end up adding the `click` handler before `addContent` is called, before the new elements exist.
If you add the handler inside `addContent`, it will work fine, since the new element will have already been added.

Alternatively, you can use jQuery's `live` method to add a handler to all elements that match the selector, no matter when they were created.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `.live()` bindings. Do it like:

```
$("a").live('click', function(event){ // !!!if any link is clicked, throw an alert 
     alert("Link clicked");
     return false;
});
```

The event method `.preventDefault()` does not work within `.live()`, `return false` instead. Since `.live()` adds an even listener to the document.body, it's always a good idea to use `.delegate()` if possible. You can tell `.delegate` the closest parent node which all elements share you need to watch. In your instance:

```
$('ul').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
     alert('Link Clicked');
     return false;
});
```

Ref.: [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: I believe that you are mistaken. The `preventDefault` method works just fine with a click event. There is an example here that specifically uses that: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

There are some different ways. You can set the events after loading the content:

```
function addContent(data) {
  $("#content").html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
  $("#content a").click(function(event){
    alert("Link clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

You can use the `live` method to catch the even when it bubbles up:

```
$("a").live('click',function(event){
  alert("Link clicked");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you are using version 1.4.2 or later of jQuery, you can use the `delegate` method, which is like the `live` method, but you can check for bubbling events in a closer scope than the body:

```
$("#content").delegate('a', 'click',function(event){
  alert("Link clicked");
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `live` method is using `delegate` on some parent of the newly created elements. This is useful if you don't want the event to be propagated to the top of the DOM hierarchy.

```
$("#parentofa").delegate("a", "click", function(event) {
    // ... my handler
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

The `<a>` element that was clicked is stored in `event.target`

Note that `preventDefault` is working here but that the event has already been propagated until the parent element (i.e. all elements in between have received the element already)